# awk commande-line

Tags: linux, awk, command-line

please, help for this commande. so I write this commande

`awk -F":" '{tab[$5]+=1} END { for (i in tab) {print i,tab[i]}}' AnnuaireBis.txt`

who give this output:

```
Ketou 4
Anneho 4
Panhouignan 4
Bohicon 2
Kpedekpo 2
```

but I want to get this format:

[image]

Please, help me. Thank you so much

Comment: `awk commande-line` is a terribly subject line for your question as it tells us nothing about your problem and so others with the same problem in future looking for solutions wouldn't be able to find your question, Please fix that to provide a meaningful subject for your question. Also replace the image of expected output with plain text as we can't test a potential solution against an image. Finally - add the sample input that would produce your expected output as we can't test a potential solution without both sample input and expected output.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: When you say `I want to get this format` do you mean a **specific** width of output line or just the columns aligned like in a table or something else? Or do you need the tool to calculate a max line width? Do you want the numbers left or right aligned (we can't tell given single digits)? I see you're getting comments suggesting to use `printf`, etc. - those may or may not be the best approach depending on your requirements and there are alternatives that may be better so please do [edit] your question to tell us what they are.

Comment: BTW, two obvious ways of doing what you want are to either: 1. use `printf` to print the first field with a fixed-length (e.g. `printf "%20s\t%i\n" i,tab[i]` for 20-character wide field string field, a tab, then an integer field)  or 2. set the output field separator (`OFS`) to a tab - e.g. with a BEGIN block: `BEGIN { OFS="\t"}`.   If these ideas help you please post the result as an answer (you can accept your own answer later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't even need to put both elements inside the `s/printf` portion :

```
mawk -F':' '$!_=sprintf("%-15s",$!_)'  
     
Ketou           4
Anneho          4
Panhouignan     4
Bohicon         2
Kpedekpo        2
```

Confirmed to work for gawk, mawk-1, mawk-2, and nawk